# ColorAccent in PreferenceScreen not working correctly in API <=22

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, android-preferences

I installed **API 22** on emulator and noticed that the RadioButtons and Buttons in ListPreferences and Preferences are not changing to the correct color that is stated in the Styles file. On API >22 it works fine. This problem only occurs in the PreferenceScreen that is used in SettingsActivity.

The color I want is **#76B900 (Green)**

What I get is the default **Android light-blue** color

[image: RadioButton]

[image: Button]

Theme is registered in the **manifest**:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.Test.App.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

**PreferencesTheme (styles.xml):**

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/settingsSubtext</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/primaryText</item>
    </style>
```

**PreferencesTheme (styles.xml (v21)):**

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/settingsSubtext</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/primaryText</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

**Colors (colors.xml):**

```
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0F0F0F</color> - Black
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color> - Black
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#C8E6C9</color> - Light Green
    <color name="colorAccent">#76B900</color> - Green
    <color name="primaryText">#FFFFFF</color> - White
    <color name="secondaryText">#757575</color> - Gray
    <color name="background">#333333</color> - Dark Gray
```

Default Android light-blue color is not set anywhere in the colors or styles file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

Add this to your styles file:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Add this to your `PreferenceTheme` style:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
```

Buttons should now be in the correct `colorAccent` color.

Comment: Works great! Thanks